# Pass component as prop in object param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I have the following Card Grid set up in Vue3:

```
<template>
  <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto">
    <div class="ml-20 pr-72">
      <h2 class="text-4xl pb-8">{{ title }}</h2>
      <p class="font-normal text-base pb-20">{{ description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-5">
      <div
        v-for="card in cards"
        :key="card.title"
        class="rounded-xl py-6 px-5 bg-cover bg-center flex flex-col justify-between items-start h-60"
        :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${card.imageUrl})` }"
      >
        <div
          class="rounded-full p-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-prospire-blue to-prospire-light-blue"
        >
          {{ card.icon }}
        </div>
        <p class="text-white font-light text-2xl">{{ card.title }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  title: string;
  description: string;
  cards: any[];
}>();
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Which i call using:

```
 <CardGrid
    :title="$t('aboutUs.cardGrid.title')"
    :description="$t('aboutUs.cardGrid.description')"
    :cards="[
      {
        title: $t('aboutUs.cardGrid.cards[0].title'),
        imageUrl:
          'https://images.pexels.com/photos/5595573/pexels-photo-5595573.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1',
        icon: <BeakerIcon />,
      },
   ]"
/>
```

This however gives me a `BeakerIcon' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof BeakerIcon'?` error.. Is it possible to pass a 3rd party component (icon in this case), to a component in a way?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pass `card.icon` as a string, such as `'BeakerIcon'` and do

```html
<div class="rounded-full p-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-prospire-blue to-prospire-light-blue">
  <component :is="card.icon" />
</div>
```

...granted the `icon` you pass has been registered as a component.

It also work without registering the component globally.

Here is an example on [sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) passing the imported components in the props.

Comment: I want to reuse the Card Grid component on multiple pages so that would mean that I would need to import all those icons in the grid component for all the pages, which is going against the reusability that I want.

Comment: With `<component :is="">`, you can pass both the registered component's name as string or the actual imported component object. So if you do `import BeakerIcon from './components/BeakerIcon.vue` with `:icon="BeakerIcon`, it should work :) So you don't have to globally register all the icons.

Comment: @Kapcash as shown in my code, that will not work since the icon is nested in the cards prop

Comment: Yes it does work. I took the liberty to add a live example on the anwser (the url was too long for a comment)